# How to change column datatype with pyarrow

Tags: parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am reading a set of arrow files and am writing them to a parquet file:

```
import pathlib
from pyarrow import parquet as pq
from pyarrow import feather
import pyarrow as pa

base_path = pathlib.Path('../mydata')

fields = [
    pa.field('value', pa.int64()),
    pa.field('code', pa.dictionary(pa.int32(), pa.uint64(), ordered=False)),
]
schema = pa.schema(fields)

with pq.ParquetWriter('sample.parquet', schema) as pqwriter:
    for file_path in base_path.glob('*.arrow'):
        table = feather.read_table(file_path)
        pqwriter.write_table(table)
```

My problem is that the `code` field in the arrow files is defined with an `int8` index instead of `int32`. The range of `int8` however is insufficient. Hence I defined a schema with a `int32` index for the field `code` in the parquet file.

However, writing the arrow table to parquet now complains that the schemas do not match.

How can I change the datatype of the arrow column? I checked the pyarrow API and did not find a way to change the schema. Can this be done without roundtripping to pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrow ChunkedArray has got a [cast](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.ChunkedArray.html#pyarrow.ChunkedArray.cast) function, but unfortunately it doesn't work for what you want to do:

```
>>> table['code'].cast(pa.dictionary(pa.int32(), pa.uint64(), ordered=False))
Unsupported cast from dictionary<values=uint64, indices=int8, ordered=0> to dictionary<values=uint64, indices=int32, ordered=0> (no available cast function for target type)
```

Instead you can cast to `pa.uint64()` and encode it to [dictionary](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.ChunkedArray.html#pyarrow.ChunkedArray.dictionary_encode):

```
>>> table['code'].cast(pa.uint64()).dictionary_encode().type
DictionaryType(dictionary<values=uint64, indices=int32, ordered=0>)
```

Here's a self contained example:

```
import pyarrow as pa

source_schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('value', pa.int64()),
    pa.field('code', pa.dictionary(pa.int8(), pa.uint64(), ordered=False)),
])

source_table = pa.Table.from_arrays([
    pa.array([1, 2, 3], pa.int64()),
    pa.array([1, 2, 1000], pa.dictionary(pa.int8(), pa.uint64(), ordered=False)),

], schema=source_schema)

destination_schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('value', pa.int64()),
    pa.field('code', pa.dictionary(pa.int32(), pa.uint64(), ordered=False)),
])

destination_data = pa.Table.from_arrays([
    source_table['value'],
    source_table['code'].cast(pa.uint64()).dictionary_encode(),
], schema=destination_schema)
```

Comment: I reported a feature request at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-11673 to support casting to a different dictionary type

Comment: @joris Thanks! I was considering doing so but decided that this was probably a known issue...